# Bugzilla email_in.pl reference several cc addresses

Tags: perl, bugzilla

When a case is created from an e-mail, I would like the list of cc present in the e-mail to be added to my default bugzilla cc list.

I was able to do it with a single cc by doing :

```
my ($cc_address) = Email::Address->parse($input_email->header('Cc'));
$fields('cc') = $cc_address->address;
```

However, what if I have several addresses, I can capture them by doing :

```
my (@cc_address) = Email::Address->parse($input_email->header('Cc'));
```

then I am not sure about how to assign the list to $fields('cc').I don't think the field does expect a list.
Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but have you tried:

```
my (@cc_address) = Email::Address->parse($input_email->header('Cc'));
my $cc_as_string = join ",", @cc_address;
$fields('cc') = $cc_as_string
```